# CREATE SEQUENCE Error : invalid value for 'INCREMENT BY'

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.Sequence1
AS decimal
START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 0.3
MINVALUE 2 MAXVALUE 4
CYCLE;
```

Error :

> An invalid value was specified for argument 'INCREMENT BY' for the given data type.

I want to create a fractional counter. What's wrong? Nope support decimal?

UPD:

When I create

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.Sequence1
AS float
....
```

SQL Server Management Studio returns error :

> The sequence object 'dbo.Sequence1' must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, or any user-defined data type that is based on one of the above integer data types.

That's why I'm trying to create a sequence with the `decimal` type.

Comment: You have several interesting things happening here. First, you defined a decimal but you did not define the scope or precision. That means it will use the default. You should always define the scope and precision. Second is you have start with defined as less than the minvalue. Not really sure what that would do but it doesn't make sense logically.

Comment: Like Gordon says below you can only use decimal with a scale of 0 (no decimal points allowed). Sequences are whole numbers only.

Comment: ok people ...thank you. What's alternatives ?

Comment: @kellismitt: When your problem can't be solved, redefine the problem. :) In this case, I'd multiply everything through by 10 (increment of 3, minvalue of 20, maxvalue of 40) and divide when you need to actually do anything with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.  The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) is quite specific that `create sequence` is for integers:

> [built_in_integer_type | user-defined_integer_type]
>
> A sequence can be defined as any **integer** type. The following types are
>   allowed.

(Emphasis is mine.)

Hence, values with decimal points are not allowed.

`decimal` is only allowed with a scale of 0 (meaning that there are no decimal points).